# How to add a menubar(QMainWindow) alongside QGraphicsView in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qmainwindow

A picture is displayed with scrollbars on a window. We can draw on it. I want to add a menubar to the same window. I tried the following, it didn't work. Nothing is shown on the window when I run this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QLineF, QPointF, QRectF, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QBrush, QColor, QPainter, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem,
                             QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
                             QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton)

class TicTacToe(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.drawLine(0,100,300,100)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,300,300)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        self.select(int(pos.x()/100), int(pos.y()/100))
        self.update()
        super(TicTacToe, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
        scene.addItem(self.tic_tac_toe)

        scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("exit.png"))

        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_R:
            self.tic_tac_toe.reset()
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.y = MyGraphicsView()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        db_action = menu.addAction("Open file")

        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 30, 20)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        self.show()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Example()

    mainWindow.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget is shown in a window if it is a child of some component of the window, in your case `self.y` is not the child of `Example`, but only an attribute, a possible solution is to set it as `centralWidget`:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.y = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.y)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        db_action = menu.addAction("Open file")

        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 30, 20)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        self.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this. Now the picture is being shown but not the menubar. What is the way to see the menubar?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Do you want a menubar or a ToolBar?

Comment: Well toobar would be appropriate since i have to add several buttons to it.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl a Menubar has a menu where actions are added, in the image that is shown in the upper left. what do you wish?

Comment: I tried this `self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')` and now a bar is shown on the top. Thanks.